# How to make a JDBC connect to Crystal Reports with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, crystalreports

I want to create a new report using Crystal Reports. I downloaded the Postgres driver but when I want to create the connection, it shows an error "JDBC Driver not found"

How can I solve it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As Guido showed you can put this `.jar` file into JRE `lib/ext` directory. But I prefer:

- create directory where you can put such `.jar` files (`c:\jars`, `/usr/local/jars`)
- set `CLASSPATH` environment variable to this directory:

  - `CLASSPATH=.;c:\jars\*;`
  - `export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/jars/*`

Answer (score 0):

Putting your driver jar file under c:/Program Files/Java/jre_xxx/lib/ext/ should do the trick.